# Android: How to tell when service is complete

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I have an activity class that contains a button.  When I click the button it starts a service that will populate my SQLite database in a separate thread.  Once the service completes I would like a textview in my activity class to display a new value from the database.

I have everything set up correctly and my database is storing the correct info.  The only thing I am still confused on is how do I tell my activity class that the service is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a broadcast when your service completes.

In your activity onResume

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = ; //Look up how to make an intent filter with an action as specified in the below service code
receiver =new BroadcastReceiver();
this.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

In your activity onPause

```
this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

In your service.

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
broadcastIntent.setAction("com.blablablaablla.ACTION_REFRESH");
this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Comment: How do I send a broadcast from the service to the activity?

Answer (score 0):

Create an Intent with your own action name "mike.intent.DB_POPULATE_DONE" or something...  it's just a string you can examine in onNewIntent() if you choose to.

Send an Intent from the Service by calling Context.startActivity().

To receive the Intent, implement Activity.onNewIntent()

Comment: I don't think I want to call startActivity() again.  I just want my controls to refresh with new values from the database.